# OneDrive API Upload Large File

Tags: javascript, onedrive, heap

I'm trying to upload a largefile.zip to my OneDrive using the API, but it's not working and it returns 'Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.' Only the upload session is successful, and uploading the bytes to the upload session is not working.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/UploadFile", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void UpFileOD( @RequestBody RequestUploadFile f ) {
        device_managementResponse response = new device_managementResponse();

        // GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/+mail to get user_id
        final String user_id = "2ada8e58-8d32-42d0-9928-9cbc3ae"; // Can change (depend on the app)

        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        try {
            // Create Upload Session
            //File file = new File(file_name.getAbsoluteFile().toString());
            File file = new File(f.file_name);
            
            if (!file.isFile())
                throw new Exception();

            long file_size = file.length();

            //final String session_url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/"+user_id+"/drive/items/root"+path+"/"+file.getName()+":/createUploadSession";
            final String session_url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/"+user_id+"/drive/items/root:/"+file.getName()+":/createUploadSession";
            // Create request header
            HttpHeaders session_header = new HttpHeaders();
            session_header.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            session_header.add("Authorization", "Bearer " +AccessToken());

            // Create request body
            JSONObject  json_request_body_nested = new JSONObject();
            json_request_body_nested.put("@odata.type","microsoft.graph.driveItemUploadableProperties");
            json_request_body_nested.put("@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior","rename");
            json_request_body_nested.put("name",file.getName());

            JSONObject json_request_body = new JSONObject();
            json_request_body.put("item", json_request_body_nested);

            // Create HttpEntity
            HttpEntity<JSONObject> session_entity = new HttpEntity<>(json_request_body,session_header );

            // Call Session Upload API
            ResponseEntity<String> session_upload = restTemplate.exchange(session_url, HttpMethod.PUT,session_entity,String.class );

            // Map response body of Session Upload
            ObjectMapper session_upload_map = new ObjectMapper();
            SessionUpload sessionUpload_obj = session_upload_map.readValue(session_upload.getBody(),SessionUpload.class);

            // Upload file
            // URL of upload file depends on the response of the upload session


            FileSystemResource fileSystemResource = new FileSystemResource(file);
//           Create request header
            HttpHeaders upload_header = new HttpHeaders();
            upload_header.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
            upload_header.setContentLength(file_size);
//          upload_header.add("Content-Range","bytes 0-"+(file_size-1)+"/"+file_size);
            upload_header.add("Content-Range","*/"+file_size);
            // Create entity
            HttpEntity<FileSystemResource> upload_entity = new HttpEntity<>(fileSystemResource,upload_header);

            // Call API
            ResponseEntity<String> uploading_file = restTemplate.exchange(sessionUpload_obj.getUploadURL(),HttpMethod.PUT,upload_entity,String.class);
//          System.out.println("Upload Success "+ "File Name: "+ file.getName() +" Path: "+path);

            System.out.println("Upload Success "+ "File Name: "+ file.getName());
            response.setRespcode(ResponseMessage.KEY_RC_SUCCESS);
            response.setMessage(ResponseMessage.getMessage(ResponseMessage.KEY_RC_SUCCESS));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response.setRespcode(ResponseMessage.KEY_RC_EXCEPTION);
            response.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

I tried to set
spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size = 3000MB
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size = 3000MB
and changed the RestTemplate to HttpURLConnection but it still does not work. I also try to set the heap size but it still does not work. I think this error is caused by creating an object that is larger than the heap size of JVM.

Comment: It appears you are setting `Content-Range` and `Content-Length` headers to the entire size of the file, you should only set it to the size of the chunk you are sending in the upload session: [driveitem_createuploadsession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession?view=odsp-graph-online) - Each chunk has a maximum size limit as well: "You can upload the entire file, or split the file into multiple byte ranges, as long as the maximum bytes in any given request is less than 60 MiB"

Comment: You might want to look at using the `Graph Api SDK` - [msgraph-sdk-java](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-java) or there is one for just `OneDrive` : [OneDrive-SDK-java](https://github.com/isac322/OneDrive-SDK-java)

Comment: I have tried to set the Content-Range to the size of the chunk, but it still does not work.

Comment: What was the error after changing your headers? Did you still try to upload the entire file at once? "Any file over 10miB should use the upload session", else you can just use the file upload endpoint. Each chunk has to be a multiple of "320 KiB (327,680 bytes)" - [driveitem_createuploadsession](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession?view=odsp-graph-online) The logic for this is to build a loop that grabs the range of bytes that is within the acceptable size limit(s) and send it via PUT request to the upload session endpoint.

Comment: I have changed my code to upload a small part of the file for a test case but it still does not work. This is the change:
upload_header.setContentLength(26);
upload_header.add("Content-Range","bytes 0-25"+"/"+file_size);
The error after I change is still the same java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space.

Comment: Are you trying to load the entire file into memory? If so, that is why you are getting the `OutOfMemoryError`, please look at using `BufferedReader` to read your file in chunks instead of trying to load the entire thing into memory: [how-to-read-a-file-in-chunks-that-is-to-large-to-be-stored-in-memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41559926/how-to-read-a-file-in-chunks-that-is-to-large-to-be-stored-in-memory), again there are existing SDKs on GitHub that will handle this for you, is there a reason you don't want to use them?